# SwiftUI: How do I display multidimensional array as sections in List?

Tags: arrays, user-interface, multidimensional-array, swiftui

I have the following object as a `var events = [[EventLog]]` and I need to loop through each inner-array and display them in a section. For example, `events[0]` might have `events[0][0].id` `events[0][1].id` and `events[0][2].id` as values and `events[1]` may only have 1 element. This is the object that I've built for reference.

#### Model Object

```
class EventLog: Identifiable  {
    let id: UUID
    let ipAddress: String
    let date: String
    let getMethod: String
    let statusCode: String
    let secondStatusCode: String
    let versionInfo: String
    
    init(ipAddress: String, date: String, getMethod: String, statusCode: String, secondStatusCode: String, versionInfo: String ){
        self.id = UUID()
        self.ipAddress = ipAddress
        self.date = date
        self.getMethod = getMethod
        self.statusCode = statusCode
        self.secondStatusCode = secondStatusCode
        self.versionInfo = versionInfo
    }
}
```

#### Attempts At Using

Doing it this way results in this error: `Referencing initializer 'init(_:content:)' on 'ForEach' requires that '[EventLog]' conform to 'Identifiable'` It should be noted that the multidimensional array is stored on a ViewModel named `landingPageVM` which is not referenced here for the sake of brevity. It is however an `@Published` property of the view model.

```
ForEach(landingPageVM.eventLogs) { logs in
            ForEach(logs)) { log in
                Text(log.id.description)
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you can change your model to a `struct` instead of a class, you'll have an easier time with this (and a lot of other things in SwiftUI):

```
struct ContentView : View {
    @State var eventLogs : [[EventLog]] = []
    
    var body: some View {
        List {
            ForEach(eventLogs, id: \.self) { logs in
                Section(header: Text("\(logs.count)")) {
                    ForEach(logs) { log in
                        Text(log.id.description)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

struct EventLog: Identifiable, Hashable  {
    let id: UUID
    let ipAddress: String
    let date: String
    let getMethod: String
    let statusCode: String
    let secondStatusCode: String
    let versionInfo: String
}
```

If you're stuck using a `class` for some reason, you can still get this behavior by doing something like:

```
extension EventLog : Hashable, Equatable {
    func hash(into hasher: inout Hasher) {
        hasher.combine(id) //etc
    }
    
    static func == (lhs: EventLog, rhs: EventLog) -> Bool {
        lhs.id == rhs.id && lhs.ipAddress == rhs.ipAddress //etc
    }
}
```

Details of the `hash` and `==` implementations may vary.

Comment: How do I get that into a section? The change from `class` to struct definitely made a difference. Can you explain why? Also, would like the sections but I keep getting `Int does not conform to View` or something along those lines. Essentially the header for the section could be logs.count to identify each section or something along those lines.

Comment: Updated with `Sections` -- sounds like you were just trying to pass an `Int` instead of a `Text`

Comment: Ahhhh I didn't realize it could accept a view like that. Sweet! I'm loving SwiftUI more and more every day.

Comment: Re: struct vs class, with struct, the compiler generates a lot more synthesized behavior for you. Also, there's a huge difference (which is worth some research for you) on passing by reference vs passing by value. SwiftUI views tend to update looking at collections of value types (ie structs).